# How to encode a string in C++ so as to not collide with seperator?

Tags: c++, database, file

I am currently developing an open-source Text-based storage utility called WaterBase. The aim is to facilitate easy saving and access of persistent key-value data, like we have in Android SharedPreferences.

The data storage scheme is like this:

`type:key:value`

The problem I am facing is that if someone uses : as a character in their key or value, the code breaks as it counts : as separator.

How do I overcome this behavior? I don't want to restrict the use of separators in user data. I looked about encoding but couldn't find any working code without external libraries.
You can have a look in the .h file [here](https://github.com/coderGtm/WaterBase/blob/main/WaterBase.h).

A mechanism that can be easily implemented in all languages instead of just C++ would be better so as to diversify the use case.

Comment: Escape it? ……..

Comment: How do I go about it?

Comment: @Dave I am not able to figure out a function to do that

Comment: We had a similar problem in one of projects. We decided to change the seperating char in user input to '\0x03', and return it to that seperating char when reporting. Everything worked and we had not any issue about the subject. Just to give a hint.

Comment: @Dariush Eivazi What if user input contained '\0x03' as a part of the string? For example in the sentence "we use \0x03 to show separator".

Comment: You are right. It is a bug and as per Morphy's law it will be trigered just now. As a guard you can check the input for that char. Can you comment that char not scaped? Anyway during the last 7 years I have not been noticed any issue about the subject. It means we have not seen any user whose name includes char '\0x03' yet.

Comment: Although that works in your case, it is critical in my use case and hence can't use it. Currently I am going with @fabian's  approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indeed want no special characters in the output string, you need to store the information about the string length beforehand. You could use an approach similar to name mangling: store the length of the next entry as integer followed by a seperator followed by the actual content:

**Example**

A string is stored as

```
<string length(decimal)> '_' <string content>
```

```
struct Entry
{
    std::string type;
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
};

void WriteMangled(std::ostream& s, std::string const& str)
{
    s << str.length() << '_' << str;
}

void ParseMangled(std::istream& s, std::string& str)
{
    size_t size;
    char c;
    if ((s >> size) && (s >> c))
    {
        assert(c == '_');
        str.resize(size, '\0');
        s.read(str.data(), size);
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Entry const& entry)
{
    WriteMangled(s, entry.type);
    WriteMangled(s, entry.key);
    WriteMangled(s, entry.value);
    return s;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, Entry& entry)
{
    ParseMangled(s, entry.type);
    ParseMangled(s, entry.key);
    ParseMangled(s, entry.value);
    return s;
}

int main() {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << Entry{ "_Td$a", "8X0_8", "foo bar baz"};

    std::string str = std::move(oss).str();
    std::cout << str << '\n';
    
    std::istringstream iss(std::move(str));
    Entry e;
    iss >> e;

    std::cout << e.type << '\n' << e.key << '\n' << e.value << '\n';
}
```

---

Adding an escape char could be simpler though, e.g. using the backslash char as character simply marking the next char as a char that is not a special character, like a seperator. The drawback is that you have to replace backslashes in the original strings with double backslashes when writing the output.

```
constexpr char EscapeChar = '\\';
constexpr char SeparatorChar = ':';

bool ReadEscapedString(std::istream& s, std::string& str)
{
    bool escaped = false;
    char c;
    while (s >> c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case EscapeChar:
            if (!(s >> c))
            {
                return false; // could not read escaped char
            }
            break;
        case SeparatorChar:
            return true;
        default:
            break;
        }
        str.push_back(c);
    }
    return true;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, Entry& entry)
{
    ReadEscapedString(s, entry.type)
        && ReadEscapedString(s, entry.key)
        && ReadEscapedString(s, entry.value);
    return s;
}

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss(R"(foo\:bar:\:baz\:\:a:x)"); // Note: Raw string literal for easier readability, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal
    Entry e;
    iss >> e;

    std::cout << e.type << '\n' << e.key << '\n' << e.value << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I am getting error running the code: error: aggregate 'std::ostringstream oss' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Comment: @coderGtm have you added `#include <sstream>`?

Comment: I didn't but adding it gives new error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::char_type*' {aka 'char*'} [-fpermissive] on the following line: s.read(str.data(), size);

Comment: Isn't there a simple escape mechanism? I want to implement this in all languages and from your code, it looks C++ specific.

Comment: @coderGtm Regarding the compilation error: The code requires the use of >= C++17, for [`std::string::data` to return a pointer to non-const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data). I added code for parsing a string using backslash as escape sequence.

Comment: @coderGtm As for being language-specific: The code can be parsed/created with any programming language: You simply need to be able to write the string length as number and be able to read a decimal number until a non-digit char is countered. Same for the approach with the escape char: Any language will allow you to go through a string one character at a time; since the question is tagged C++, I simply used c++ streams...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @fabian. Initially, I didn't get my head around your answer and thought it was C++ specific so preferred the escape char approach. Now as I read more about your answer and your description, it hit me right. In fact, it's a better approach I think.